# Matlab Obtain output of GUI listbox

Tags: matlab

This is my first real time using a gui so I'll try my best to explain. I've created a simple gui that contains 2 different listboxes which contain several variables that happen to be arrays that I created earlier in my code. I want to be able to take the variables that the user selected in the listboxes and use them elsewhere in my code. For example, I have:

```
Listbox one containing A, B, C
and
Listbox two containing X, Y, Z
In the GUI
```

and I want to take the arrays the user selects and perform the following interactions with them:

```
resultA=intersect(Res,output1);
resultB=intersect(Res,output2);
```

So if they select 'A' in the first one it would essentially do:

```
resultA=intersect(Res,A);
```

I've mostly been using Matlab's interactive "guide" as I learn how to do this.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-guide-gui-example.html#bt420ve-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your listboxes `h.ListBox1` and `h.Listbox2`.

To get the output, you would do the following:

`StrA=get(h.List1ox1,'String');
 resultA=StrA{get(h.ListBox1,'Value')};`

You could do the same for the other listbox and continue with your code.